# Handling lists with CoreData in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swiftui, swiftui-list

I started using CoreData with SwiftUI. After following this [series of tutorials](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/introduction-to-using-core-data-with-swiftui). And I can already read an write data to CoreData.

But things are still fuzzy when I need to handle lists.
I now have code like this:

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        List(self.myList.keys.sorted(), id: \.self) { location in
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {
                    self.showingList.toggle()
                    .....
                }) {
                    Text(location)
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                }
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }

    .....
}
```

Here myList is just a dictionary, which I previously loaded from some Core Data entity.

What I want to do now is to have my Core Data DB to be synchronized with my list, when I remove items from the list or change (or add) some elements. I presume that should be easy if I do the right thing using the proper SwiftUI wrapper, but I need to find some clear tutorial for that. Any recommendation would be useful.

Comment: If you type "swiftui core data list tutorial" in google one of the first links is [Core Data with SwiftUI Tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/9335365-core-data-with-swiftui-tutorial-getting-started) - this should cover all your basic questions.

Comment: There are indeed a bunch of tutorials to handle Core Data with SwiftUI, but I haven't seen anything to take care of lists. I'll take a look at your suggestion. Thanks.